# strpos doesn't match a string : characterset issue?

Tags: php, character-encoding, strpos

a `strpos` works or not depending on the parsed string source (entered manually or provided by a third-party mechanism) :

```
index.php?option=com_ars&view=release&id=8
```

The strpos instruction is

```
$debug = "found '?' : " . ((strpos($url, '?') === false) ? 'false' : 'true');
```

The strpos always return false.

I tried `mb_strpos`, I tried all sorts of en/de-coding to no avail (`utf8_encode`, `utf8_decode`, even using `sprintf`, `iconv`, ...).

I best hint I have up to know is that, when the string is provided by a 3rd-party mechanism a **`convert_uudecode` gives an error**

```
Warning: convert_uudecode(): The given parameter is not a valid uuencoded string
```

while for the manually entered it returns 8AX9|�3".

I'm no php specialist at all, but this make me think of a characterset problem.

Any idea on how I should do my strpos ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I see that there is one parentheses "(" too much. (you have 3 opening "(", and 2 closing ")").
Secondly, if you want your variable $ok to be true if he FINDS the "?" sign, then you should test with !==

```
$ok = strpos($url, '?') !== false;
```

$ok will now be true if a quotation mark "?" is found.